# applying a function with different field

Tags: coq

Is there a way, to apply an hypotesis to our goal in Coq ?

For example:

**Hypothesis:**

```
1 subgoal
a : nat
l1 : list nat
l2 : list nat
H : Prefix (a :: l1) l2
IHl1 : Prefix l1 l2 -> sum l1 <= sum l2
```

**Goal**

```
______________________________________(1/1)
sum (a :: l1) <= sum l2
```

I know that if i could do : apply IHl1 , i could have a result like Prefix (a::l1) l2 and after i will be able to do an assumption !
But i can't do the apply because it's giving me this error : 
*Error: Impossible to unify "sum l1 <= sum l2" with "sum (a :: l1) <= sum l2".*

**Instructions**

**Fixpoint**

```
Fixpoint sum (l: list nat) : nat := match l with
  | nil => 0
  | a::t => a + sum t
  end.
```

**Lemma**

```
Lemma parte2_1_c : forall l1 l2, Prefix l1 l2 -> sum l1 <= sum l2.
Proof.
intros.
induction l1.
simpl.
SearchAbout(_<=_).
apply le_0_n.
SearchAbout(sum).
(*must continue but do not know how to do it...*)
```

So... How may i able to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a :: l1` is different from `l1` so you won't be able to use that hypothesis.

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Definition Prefix : forall {t1}, list t1 -> list t1 -> Prop := fun _ l1 l2 =>
  exists l3, l1 ++ l3 = l2.

Conjecture C1 : forall t1 (x1 : t1) l1 l2, Prefix (x1 :: l1) l2 -> exists l3, l2 = x1 :: l3.
Conjecture C2 : forall n1 n2 n3, n1 <= n2 -> n3 + n1 <= n3 + n2.
Conjecture C3 : forall t1 (x1 : t1) l1 l2, Prefix (x1 :: l1) (x1 :: l2) -> Prefix l1 l2.
Hint Resolve C1 C2 C3.

Lemma parte2_1_c : forall l1 l2, Prefix l1 l2 -> sum l1 <= sum l2.
Proof.
intros.
induction l1.
simpl.
SearchAbout(_<=_).
apply le_0_n.
assert (H3 : exists l3, l2 = a :: l3) by info_eauto with *.
destruct H3.
subst.
simpl in *.
Abort.
```

You also introduced too many variables before performing induction. That made the induction hypothesis less general.

```
Lemma parte2_1_c : forall l1 l2, Prefix l1 l2 -> sum l1 <= sum l2.
Proof.
intros l1.
induction l1.
info_eauto with *.
intros.
assert (H3 : exists l3, l2 = a :: l3) by info_eauto with *.
destruct H3.
subst.
simpl in *.
info_eauto with *.
Qed.
```

Comment: Holy crap ! xD
I have never seen that function "info_eauto" :O

Comment: Don't get too excited. `eauto` is kind of slow.

Comment: I can't apply the : "info_eauto with *." getting an error : "Syntax error: '.' or '...' expected after [tactic:tactic] (in [subgoal_command]).
"

Comment: Did you include the `Require Import`, the `Conjecture`, and the `Hint Resolve` parts? `eauto` is a form of automated theorem proving. But it's more difficult to search for proofs in intuitionistic higher-order dependent-type logic than in classical first-order untyped logic.

Comment: hummm, can't we solve this without automated theorem ? Because i would really like to see that ... I'm afraid that my teacher won't like it (by doing it automatic) on the exam test

Comment: Doesn't `info_eauto` output a message? That message is the steps `info_eauto` took to prove your goal. You can substitute the `info_eauto` part with the contents of that message. By the way, the `Conjecture`s are facts that I took the liberty of assuming. They still haven't been proved.

Comment: Right. (Comments must be 15 characters in length.)